# Recursion in java and maintaining states of variables across stacks

Tags: java, recursion, tree, pass-by-value

I was trying to solve a problem in BST where the question was "Check if all leaves are at same level"

In this question, I need to keep incrementing the level per stack call but also maintain a value across all calls, the maximum level. Along with this, I need to return a boolean with the result.

It is simple enough to solve, I need to keep doing down the tree, I did this

```
int maxlevel = 0;
public boolean allAtSameLevel(Node root, int level){
    if(root== null){
        return false;
    }
    if(root.left== null && root.right == null){
        if(maxlevel == 0){
            maxlevel = level;
        }
        return(level== maxlevel);
    }
    return allAtSameLevel(root.left, level+1) && allAtSameLevel(root.right, level+1) ;
}
```

My problem is that for a value that needs to be shared, I have to maintain an instance variable in java. Is there a better way to do this? My confusion is that since, it's going to go all the way to the right leaf first and then go up, passing the value won't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to communicate the depth of the subtree back to the higher level of the stack, but doing so only when both right and left depths are the same. You can do it with a simple recursive function:

```
int eqDepth(Node n) {
    if (n == null) return 0;     // This is a leaf, its subtree depth is zero
    int dLeft = eqDepth(n.left); // Make two recursive calls
    int dRight = eqDepth(n.right);
    // If one of the depths is negative, or the depths are different,
    // report it by returning negative 1:
    if (dLeft < 0 || dRight < 0 || dLeft != dRight) return -1;
    return 1+dLeft; // It's the same as dRight
}
```

With this function in hand, you can code `allAtSameLevel` in one line:

```
public boolean allAtSameLevel(Node root) {
    return eqDepth(root) >= 0;
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Tiby8e) It starts off with an unbalanced tree and gets a `-1`

```
     a
   /   \
  b     c
 / \   / \
d   e  f  -
```

then adds the missing node

```
     a
   /   \
  b     c
 / \   / \
d   e  f  g
```

and gets a positive result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i think this solution is comparing the left and right of each root and returning the values instead of the leaf nodes of the entire tree. I tested it and it would return a value >=0 as long as the root has two children.

Comment: @12rad Oops, I forgot to add one to the result of the prior invocation. It works now - take a look at the demo.

Comment: Ya, that worked. So, instead of going down and calculating the level, you've taken the bottom up approach to return the values and add it and then compare. I think I need to practice more! But thank you.